# Is CRM 2011 workflow code re-entrant?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

As I understand, CRM workflow is trigged when a workflow execution request is received on the server. My question is, if there're many reqeusts arrived at the server to trig the same workflow, will there be multiple instances of the same workflow? i.e. is the workflow code re-entrant? This could lead some server side race condition issue.

Thanks~

Comment: just to clarify, do you mean multiple instances of the same workflow on the same record?

Comment: Actually, my workflow will take action on multiple records based on a query.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow can create multiple instances on a same record. For exameple if you define a workflow which will be running when updating picklist field A. Then you update the field 4 times, and you will see 4 running results about the workflow on the record. To avoid it, you can use conditions to check its running context such as trigger when field A equal XXX. Hope these comments can help you. :)

Comment: Could you give some more details about "*check its running context such as trigger*" part? Thanks.